# If $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, must $X$ be $\sigma(Y)$-measurable?

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

The question is the following:

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. If $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, must $X$ be $\sigma(Y)$-measurable?

I have no idea how to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just a tip: if the problem is asking you whether a statement holds rather than asking you to prove a statement, most likely that statement doesn't hold :-) )

**Hint**: Let $X$ be a a random variable that takes on the values $\pm 1$ with equal probability on your favorite probability space, and let $Y=X^2$. What is $\sigma(Y)$?